# Eliminar más de 200.000 registros en SQL

Tags: sql, delete

tengo la siguiente inquietud.

Tengo una base de datos con millones de registros en SQL server, constantemente debemos eliminar muchos registros de 200 mil a quinientos mil, lo hacemos con un delete especificando una condición y esa condición es de acuerdo a unos listados de ID, (delete from x where ID: 56,67,77,87...n) al realizarse el delete de esa manera el servidor se tuesta y arroja un error, por lo que debemos eliminar alrededor de a 30 mil registros, de qué manera podríamos eliminarlos todos de manera masiva.

Comment: ¿Y el error es...? ¿Es una tabla de auditoría o algo similar? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Hazte un script con un bucle que borre por ejemplo cada 1000 y haga commit. Así te evitarás ese problema. Piensa que el servidor tiene que guardarse en memoria el rollback